# Странное поведение собственной функции E^x при некоторых значениях

Tags: c, функции, рекуррентность

Имеется, основная часть, где мы вводим x и выводим экспоненту из нашей собственной функции и экспоненту из библиотечной функции. А так же функции рекурентного вычисления e в степени x.

Немного объясню принцип работы функции.
Вычисляем саму экспоненту в рекурентной форме, при помощи формулы указанной на картинке.
В качестве точности вычисления берем DBL_MIN.
Так же как условие в цикле while добавляем

`sum != fabsl(an)`

Нужно оно для выхода из цикла при превращении sum в inf.
Но также прибавляем DBL_EPSILON к an для правильной работы этого условия при x = -1; Это немного уменьшит точность при огромных x, но не критично.

`sum != fabsl(an) + DBL_EPSILON`

**Программа работает корректно с значениями x в диапазоне ( ~-10 ; ∞ )**

Сделал вывод всех sum и an с указанием итерации. И при больших отрицательных x, функция ведет себя странно, sum перестает меняться.

Сделал вывод мантиссы и порядка, на определенной итерации они так же перестают меняться. Кажется происходит следующее, в какой-то момент порядок an становится слишком маленьким, а для sum он почти не меняется. Но у нас происходит операция сложения, а для этого нужно выровнять порядки, но при попытке сделать это, получается так, что число an с преобразованным порядком, меньше чем число, которое можно быть записано в (long double) sum.

**Как можно решить эту проблему и заставить sum меняться?**

*Здесь видно как sum перестает меняться (x = -22):*

[image: Здесь видно как sum перестает меняться]

*Ниже изображение с рекурентной формулой. В качестве первого члена суммы берем 1*
[image: Рекурентная формула]

Исходный код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <float.h>

long double exponenta(long double x);

int main()
{
    long double x;
    printf("Vvedite x\n");
    scanf("%Lf", &x);
    printf("exponenta^%Lf = %.64Lf\n\n", x, exponenta(x));
    printf("exp(%Lf) =      %.64Lf\n", x, expl(x));
    return 0;
}

long double exponenta(long double x)
{
    long double an = 1.0, sum = 1.0;
    long double i = 0.0;
    
    // 4 строчки ниже, это строчки дебага
    long double mantissa_for_sum = 0;
    int poriadok_for_sum = 0;
    long double mantissa_for_an = 0;
    int poriadok_for_an = 0;
    
    do
    {
        an = an*(x/(long double)(i+1.0));
        sum += an;
        i += 1.0;

        // 4 строчки ниже, это строчки дебага
        printf("\nsum = %.100Lf    \nan = %.100Lf    \ni = %.Lf\n", sum, an, i);
        mantissa_for_sum = frexpl ( sum , &poriadok_for_sum ); // раскладываем sum на мантиссу и порядок
        mantissa_for_an = frexpl ( an , &poriadok_for_an ); // раскладываем an на мантиссу и порядок
        printf ("\t mantissa(sum) ===== %.100Lf, poriadok(sum) ===== %d\n \tmantissa(an) ===== %.100Lf, poriadok(an) ===== %d\n\n\n\n", mantissa_for_sum, poriadok_for_sum, mantissa_for_an, poriadok_for_an );

    } while (fabsl(an) > DBL_MIN && sum != fabsl(an) + DBL_EPSILON); // sum != fabsl(an) => inf при больших значениях x // + DBL_EPSILON необходимо для корректной работы отлова inf, без него при x = -1 на второй итерации sum становится равно an
    
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: я правильно понимаю, что вы хотите как-то сложить числа с разностью больше 20 порядков, что бы результат был отличен от бОльшего числа?

Comment: Поведение, когда `x+y==x`, где y мало по сравнению с x - нормально для вещественной арифметики. 15-16 значащих цифр в double, пятьдесят ну никак не получить

Comment: Да, верно. Но есть ли способы реализовать такое сложение?

Comment: Несколько шагов можно сделать с помощью Kahan summation, или просто от меньших к большим, но радикально это не поможет. Библиотеки длинной арифметики есть типа GMP. Но в чём реальная задача? Зачем вам считать экспоненту самостоятельно.?

Comment: ну в целом есть. но вопрос тогда неправильно назван) спросили как повысить точность вычислений дробных чисел, сразу бы дубликаты нашли) Но вообще это тема весьма серьёзных книг. Из самого простого - https://habr.com/ru/post/523654/ может подарить немного знаков.

Comment: В целом задача стоит побороть очень дотошного преподавателя) и максимально приблизиться к библиотечной функции экспоненты

Comment: Ну да, известный факт, что нужно складывать от мЕньших к бОльшим, чтобы максимально сохранить точность. Вам либо нужно накопить все вычисленные слагаемые и после остановки сложить правильным образом. Либо найти номер последнего слагаемого и ещё раз пройтись по вычислениям уже в обратную сторону.

Comment: Если программа корректно работает в положительном диапазоне, то не стоит ли воспользоваться тем, что e^(-x) = 1/e^x?

Comment: А вообще я бы, наверное, считал в небольшом диапазоне, где все можно точно просчитать заранее, а потом приводил к нужному значению умножением на e в целочисленной степени, которое можно просто посчитать с помощью метода быстрого возведения в степень. Если задача ставится именно просчитать e^x, а не e^x как сумму конкретного ряда...

Comment: @Harry Ваш математический трюк действительно сработал. Теперь у программы корректный вывод при любом x. 
Большое спасибо всем ответившим!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Благодарность @Harry за вот такой математический трюк:
`e^(-x) = 1/e^x`

Теперь у программы правильный вывод при любом x. Да, точность всего ~20 знаков после запятой, но этого достаточно для моего задания.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <float.h>

long double exponenta(long double x);

int main()
{
    long double x;
    printf("Vvedite x\n");
    scanf("%Lf", &x);
    printf("exponenta^%Lf = %.200Lf\n\n", x, exponenta(x));
    printf("exp(%Lf) =      %.200Lf\n", x, expl(x));
    return 0;
}

long double exponenta(long double x)
{
    long double an = 1.0, sum = 1.0;
    long double i = 0.0;
    short flag = 0;
    
    if(x < 0.0)
    {
        x *= -1.0;
        flag = 1;
    }
    
    do
    {
        an = an*(x/(long double)(i+1.0));
        sum += an;
        i += 1.0;
    } while (fabsl(an) > DBL_MIN && sum != fabsl(an)); // sum != fabsl(an) => inf при больших значениях x
    
    if(flag == 1)
        sum = 1 / sum;
    
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: есть ещё секретный способ деления пополам :  `exp( - 22 ) = exp( -11 ) * exp( - 11 )`